# Is my PositiveSSL certificate chain configured properly?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, node.js

I am using NodeJS to host an HTTPS Express server. My server configuration is as follows:

```
var options = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('domain_com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('domain_com-bundle.crt')
}

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8082, function() {...} );
```

I followed instructions from this [website](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1091/0/certificate-installation--nginx) to concatenate the .crt and .ca-bundle files.

UPDATE:
Updated my code, but it still gives the same error

```
var options = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('domain_com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('domain_com.crt'),
    ca:   fs.readFileSync('domain_com.ca-bundle')
}

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8082, function() {...} );
```

With this code I did not follow the instruction on the previous link, but rather included each file individually into the https module in NodeJS

Now, my problem arises when I try to visit my website using Chrome 56 on mobile Android. Everything works like it should with Chrome on desktop.

I ran a SSL analyzer and this was returned: [Broken Cert Chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6feo.png)

To put it simple I have probably tried every key/cert/bundle combination possible trying to get this to work, but chrome still gives ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

I'm not exactly 100% sure of what I am doing because this is my first time ever setting up and SSL certificate, so just let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Take a look at the concatenated file (`domain_com.crt`). Does it contain two certificates (two huge base64 strings separated from each other)? Please pass each base64 string to `openssl x509 -text -noout` and look at their internal fields, also edit here and add that info.

Comment: The .crt file only has one certificate block in it. Also what do you mean pass each string to openssl x509 -text -noout?

Comment: One block = bad. It should have two.

Comment: Lol alright, I trust you know what you are talking about, but that .crt file came directly from my registrar. Any idea what certificate I am missing? The bundle file has three certs and the .crt file has one just to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your help @kubanczyk but I just figured it out after about 4 hours of racking my brain. I don't think I would have ever thought to append that file to the original .crt file, though. Every resource I found was explaining how it had to be the bundle file. Anyways, seems to be fixed now, and I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For my specific situation I was using Namecheap.com as my registrar with the Comodo PositiveSSL certificate. To fix the issue I had with the cert not working on Chrome 56 for Android, I appended [this](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl_trust/blob/master/intermediate_ca/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt) file to the end of the .crt file provided by Namecheap.